# Is there a way concatenate a cell value into a page reference function to reference pages with the name of that cell value?

Tags: google-sheets, variables, reference

Essentially I am creating a budget that utilizes 2 sheets and want to be able to create copies without manually having to manually update each page name reference with every new set.

I have pages named as "month Overview" "month Spending" and plan to change the names with each copy for every month going forward.

I will put "January" in C2 of the page "January Overview" and will have cells on that page referencing cells on the page "January Spending". I want the month to update dynamically to fill in the page reference formula.

I have not had any luck with my formatting. I am able to get the string of the page name using the indirect function but can not get it to work within the page reference.

[Current page that puts my spending into categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJBHU.png)

[Page that I want to reference those values in to compare to my proposed budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkehe.png)

I have tried to mess with combining the following:

`=INDIRECT("C2")&" Spending"`

and a page reference like

`='January Spending'!I3`

One example I tried was

`='(INDIRECT("C2")&" Spending")'!I3`

but I end up continuously getting an unresolved sheet name error.

I've been digging and cant seem to find any examples of this so I am curious if it is even possible. Any tips here would be lovely - thanks in advance! (also don't judge my spending, its a wip lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```cpp
=INDIRECT(C2&" Spending!I3")
```

Comment: I knew I was complicating it too much. Thank you!!